# Duplicate function name affecting Jasmine tests in Meteor

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, meteor, jasmine, meteor-velocity

I have recently started working with [Meteor](https://www.meteor.com/), and trying to start off as I mean to go on by testing well. To this end, I am using the [Velocity](http://velocity.meteor.com/) test runner and using [Jasmine](http://jasmine.github.io/) for the actual tests.

Take the very simple case where I have a file in the server directory called `hello.js`, which contains our old favourite

```
var helloWorld = function () {
    return "Hello World";
};
```

Then in my test directory, well 'tests/jasmine/server/unit' I have a test file `sampleTest.js` containing the basic test suite

```
describe("Hello World", function() {
    it("should return hello world", function() {
        expect(helloWorld()).toBe("Hello World");
    });
});
```

Velocity reports all tests passing, everyone is happy. If I change the original `helloWorld` function to return something different, the test fails as expected.

If, however, a second function, of the same name with a different output existed somewhere in the project, e.g.

```
var helloWorld = function () {
    return "Goodbye World";
};
```

Then this would break the test, but the other version of it passes the test.

Extrapolating from this simplified example, how then do I ensure each function is uniquely named to avoid this problem?

Is my question more a result of my incomplete grasp of Meteor fundamentals (or JS/testing fundamentals in general)?

Comment: If two functions have the same name in the same scope, they won't stay that way for very long. Meteor will find them, signal the error, say where it is and won't even start. Because Meteor runs JSLint checks which catch this kind of thing. I think your question is about something very theoretical and unlikely to happen. Your grasp of testing is fine. I wish I had started testing much earlier than I actually did.

Comment: That's what I had hoped/assumed would happen, but Meteor didn't throw any errors

Comment: You're right, I was wrong. I've just tested it. Let's leave aside the fact that you will probably never make this mistake - I don't think I ever have - the fact is that Javascript is very lenient about some things, so in this case I guess that the second version of the function just simply overrides the first. I will test this.

Comment: Yup, the last function will always override the first. The same in a Meteor helper. But personally I wouldn't spend time worrying about this happening.